# Why when counting the duration when the transform is moving forward and backward it's start counting from 0 again instead sum it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At top

```
public Text[] debbugingUiTexts;

private float rounded;
private float t;

    void Start()
    {
        t = 0.0f;
        originPosition = transform.position;
    }
```

Then in Update i'm updating the ui text. The duration for example is 10 seconds so when the transform is moving towards the target it's counting to 10 then when the transform is moving backward it's counting to 11 and then starting to count from 0 to 10.

I want to count all the duration for both sides moving when moving to the target and back it should be counting to 20 overall.  the duration is 10 but for each side. but in the ui text it's showing the numbers from 1 to 10 then 11 and then 0 to 10.

```
void Update()
    {
        var v1 = destinationTransform.position - transform.position;
        if (v1.magnitude < 0.01f)
        {
            t = 0.0f;
            originPosition = transform.position;
            state = TransitionState.MovingBackward;
        }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
        {
            t = 0.0f;
            originPosition = transform.position;
            state = TransitionState.MovingBackward;
        }

        if (go)
        {
            if (updateOriginPosition == true)
            {
                originPosition = transform.position;
                updateOriginPosition = false;
            }

            if (col != null && enableCollider)
            {
                Destroy(col);
                Destroy(transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>());
                enableCollider = false;
            }

            switch (state)
            {
                case TransitionState.MovingTowards:
                    var v = destinationTransform.position - transform.position;
                    if (v.magnitude < 0.001f)
                    {
                        state = TransitionState.Transferring;
                        originTransform = destinationTransform;
                        timer = 0;
                        return;
                    }

                    t += Time.deltaTime;
                    float s = t / duration;

                    rounded = Mathf.Round(t);
                    debbugingUiTexts[0].text = rounded.ToString();

                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(originPosition,
                        destinationTransform.position, curve.Evaluate(s));

                    break;

                case TransitionState.MovingBackward:
                    t += Time.deltaTime;
                    float s1 = t / duration;

                    rounded = Mathf.Round(t);
                    debbugingUiTexts[0].text = rounded.ToString();

                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(originPosition,
                        transform.parent.position,
                        curve.Evaluate(s1));

                    break;
```

Comment: How about not resetting it to `t = 0.0f;` then?

Comment: @derHugo I tried to remove the reset line in this part if (v1.magnitude < 0.01f)
        {
            t = 0.0f; removed the t =0.0f;   but then the transform is not moving back using the lerp as before the transform just "jumping"  back to the original position and that's because i'm not reseting the t. so in one hand the counting is working and never stop in the other hand the lerping has no affect because t is not reseted.

Comment: Use different variables one for the count and one for the interpolation?

Comment: right thanks i will do it using two variables.

Comment: Also also ment the reset when switching the key down at the top ;)